# Php form Post for more than 500 POST parameters

Tags: php, http-post

I have tried to post a php form with more than 500 data field. I tried by jquery serialization the form data and then submit the form . I get the same result with that too. Can any one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you using `GET` method or `POST`?

Comment: have check few post before send 500 request?

Comment: post method i am using Alok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to post one and one value and then save the value in a session-array.

In your front page you would do this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function update_post(){
        $("#/*Text Input ID Name*/").load("update_post_session.php?name=(session_array_name)&group=(session_name)&value="+ document.getElementById('Text Input ID').value.split(" ").join("_")); // .split(" ").join("_") does replace ALL spaces with underscores, this line can be used more times with different ID and value and name etc
    }
    // To update the session automaticly
        setInterval(update_post, 10000); // This will update the form each 10 seconds, if you have over 500 inputs I would recommend minimum 5 seconds so it will not cause the client to experience any downtime to form
</script>
```

In your update_post_session.php you will have this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $session_group = $_GET['session_name'];
    $session_name  = $_GET['name'];
    $value = $_GET['value'];
    /*Replacing "_" with " "*/ $value = str_replace("_", " ", $value);
    $_SESSION[$session_group][$session_name] = $value;
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function update_post(stop){var id = 0;
        var whileinter = setInterval(function(){
            if(id>stop){clearInterval(whileinter);}
            $("#"+id).load("update_post_session.php?name=(session_array_name)&group=(session_name)&value="+ document.getElementById('Text Input ID').value.split(" ").join("_")); // .split(" ").join("_") does replace ALL spaces with underscores, this line can be used more times with different ID and value and name etc
            id++;
        }, 1);
    }
    // To update the session automaticly
         var inter = setInterval(update_post(500 /* the amount of input boxes you have */), 10000); // This will update the form each 10 seconds, if you have over 500 inputs I would recommend minimum 5 seconds so it will not cause the client to experience any downtime to form
</script>
```

And in your html, input form whatever you will id it from 0 to amount of forms to post BY ORDER (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 20 ... 50 ... 200 ... 500 <- END)

Comment: Richard, Then I have to call that function for numerous time to post my form  I think. Or when can I call update_post function? can u plz explain

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran, you can now take a look at the edit